# How to reset admin or any user password in Umbraco?

Tags: passwords, umbraco, umbraco7, reset-password, umbraco8

No way to reset password in umbraco 8.
I have searched all solutions in umbraco forum & stack overflow.
Trying solution in https://our.umbraco.com/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/91117-how-does-umbraco-hash-member-passwords-and-for-a-bonus-can-i-create-a-member-using-a-hashed-password but nothing.

Comment: Is that for an admin? Can't you use the Forgot password option?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class as below and run the project:

```
using System.Web.Security;
using Umbraco.Core.Composing;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;
using Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers;

namespace Project
{
    [RuntimeLevel(MinLevel = RuntimeLevel.Run)]
    public class StartingComposer : IUserComposer
    {
        public void Compose(Composition composition)
        {
            composition.Components().Append<StartingEvent>();
        }
    }
    public class StartingEvent : IComponent
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService; 
        public StartingEvent(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            var adminUser = _userService.GetUserById(-1);
            adminUser.Username = adminUser.Email = "admin@gmail.com";
            adminUser.FailedPasswordAttempts = 0;
            adminUser.IsLockedOut = false;
            adminUser.IsApproved = true;
            adminUser.RawPasswordValue = (Membership.Providers["UsersMembershipProvider"] as UsersMembershipProvider)?.HashPasswordForStorage("Admin123*");
            userService.Save(adminUser);
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
        }
        public void Terminate()
        {
        }
    }
}
```